# tfield.onchange not fired when we reset tfield to oldvalue

Tags: onchange, freepascal, tfield

the Event tfield.onChange is  fired when we update a record but not fired when we reset  it to oldvalue ( ex cancelUpdates or simply cancel ) . Can we change this behavior?